# How to use Mybatis Pagehelper plugin in Gradle Project?

Tags: java, spring-boot, mybatis

I am currently developing an app that deals with lots of data and while calling to backend the system becomes slow that yields low performance so I tried to use backend pagination and for that. I am trying to use Mybatis PageHelper plugin so can anyone help me how to use it with the Gradle project or there is any better technique than this?

Please find below are the configs and code.

**mybatis-conf.xml**

```
<configuration>
    <plugins>
        <plugin interceptor="com.github.pagehelper.PageInterceptor">
        <value>
            <property name="dialect" value="mysql"/>
            <property name="offsetAsPageNum" value="true"/>
            <property name="rowBoundsWithCount" value="true"/>
            <property name="pageSizeZero" value="true"/>
            <property name="reasonable" value="true"/>
        </value>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</configuration>
```

**mapper**

```
public interface AdmissionMapper {
    Page<AdmissionDto> findByPage();
}
```

xml

```
<select id="findByPage" resultType="com.techarttrekkies.imagineinquirysys.model.dto.AdmissionDto">
    SELECT
    a.id,
    a.people_id,
    a.admission_status_id,
    a.year_level_id,
    a.academic_year_id,
    a.created_at,
    a.updated_at,
    a.photo,
    astat.name
    admission_status_name
    FROM
    admission a
    INNER JOIN 
    ${packageName}.admission_status astat
    on a.admission_status_id = astat.id
    LEFT JOIN student_classroom sc on
    sc.admission_id = a.id
    <where>
        <if test="id != null and id != ''">
            AND a.id = #{id}
        </if>
        <if test="yearLevelId != null and yearLevelId != ''">
            AND a.year_level_id = #{yearLevelId}
        </if>
        <if test="admissionStatusId != null and admissionStatusId != ''">
            <!-- sc.admission_id IS NULL -->
            AND admission_status_id =#{admissionStatusId}
        </if>
        <if test="peopleId != null">
            and a.people_id = #{peopleId}
        </if>
    </where>
    order by a.admission_status_id
</select>
```

**service**

```
public interface AdmissionService {
    Page<AdmissionDto> findByPage(Integer start, Integer size);
}
```

**service implementation**

```
public class AdmissionServiceImpl implements AdmissionService {
    @Override
    public Page<AdmissionDto> findByPage(Integer start,Integer size) {
        PageHelper.startPage(start,size);
        return admissionMapper.findByPage();
    }
}
```

**controller**

```
public class AdmissionController {
    @Autowired
    private AdmissionService admissionService;

    @PostMapping("/findByPage")
    public Object findByPage(@RequestBody PageNumAndSize page){
        Page<AdmissionDto> admissions = admissionService.findByPage(page.getStart(), page.getSize());
        PageInfo<AdmissionDto> result = new PageInfo<>(admissions);
        return result;      
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a gradle dependency and config like mybatis-conf.xml, Your code seem no problem. you can debug into com.github.pagehelper.PageInterceptor class to see if it has been called.